change default name for eMMC to other than mmcblkX
With previous platform the boot device was mtdX, and there could be only one sd-card, always appearing in the system as mmcblk0.
New system has internal eMMC, which is mmcblkX, as well as may have sd-card with same mmcblkX type of name.
The worst thing about this new setup is the names interchange from boot to boot, sometimes eMMC is device 0 and sd-card is device 1, sometimes other way round. Well I may be able to create symlink device file in /dev/ in some script (e.g. hotplug) figuring out what device is where and assign fixed names, but at this time it looks ugly.
Question - is there any way to ask Linux, from the very boot or initial device initialization, to name eMMC device with different name? For example, /dev/mmcblk0 will always be an sd-card, and /dev/emmcblk0 be an eMMC?
I must admit I did not perform much research because I have no idea what to start with, and maybe research will be just time lost because it is simply impossible (e.g. due to same driver serving these devices without such way of customization).

Same problem as with network cards (it was never certain which of your cards ended up being eth0 and which eth1, especially as USB network cards became common in laptops)! That's why we have the network card renaming feature (which a lot of people complain about, because they want their network card to be called eth0, not enp9s0, even if the latter stays the same, no matter what USB device they have plugged in when they boot)!
For storage, there's a few easy solutions here. Question: are you in control of what's on these cards, in the sense of, do you format them? Because then you can control their uuid, and will always find the same card under /dev/disk/by-uuid . No extra trickery needed! Most operating system installers will, if forced to work with raw partitions, actually set up an /etc/fstab that lists UUID=somestring instead of /dev/sdaX (for example), exactly because of the problems you describe.
If that's not the case, you can often locate the block device via /dev/disk/by-path. The format is generally something like
{attachment bus type}-{attachment bus address}-{device connection bus}-{number}[-part{number}]

in my case, in one of my servers, the first SATA disk appear as
pci-0000:00:1f.2-ata-1

(because it's a SATA controller on PCIexpress, so we have the PCI "bus space", connecting to a logical ATA bus)
and one of the NVMe SSDs as
pci-0000:03:1f.4-nvme-1

I don't have my rockchip aarch64 laptop with me, but you'll find things like pci-0000:01:00.0-platform-rtsx_pci_sdmmc.0 for eMMC cards directly attached to your system's SoC.

Thanks. I do certainly know where device file points to - through device tree. I may not be able to universally control what on the card, and card may be replaced with another one. And I am afraid UUID may be same everywhere as devices may be cloned using dd. You mentioned renaming feature but did not say anything about it! If it is not applicable directly, could you please explain the mechanism.

network card renaming: It's in udev, but it's not applicable here. So, if you know via devicetree how the cards are attached, then my answer already has the easiest solution for you. /dev/disk/by-path does exactly what you need: provide reliable names for things you know the way they are attached. No further research needed :) And: it's done by the same mechanism that sets up network card renaming, so also, that question answered. You want /dev/disk/by-path/, it's exactly meant for your use case!

Hm it seems I should have said it is an openwrt. Assuming all the Linux is the same is always a big problem. Yes, in Ubuntu I see the /dev/disk, in openwrt it is missing.
